# How do you download sap commerce cloud for local use?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Is there any way to download commerce cloud to use locally? Software center shows *No data* and we can't download anything.

Also, can we use a public commerce cloud instance to build a storefront? In the case where we can't download cloud commerce but we want to build a storefront.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow these easy steps below to quickly get up and running with a new spartacus app using the public commerce cloud instance.

1. `ng new mystore --style=scss`
2. `cd mystore`
3. `ng add @spartacus/schematics --baseUrl https://spartacustraining.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8443 –occPrefix /occ/v2/ --baseSite electronics-spa --pwa --ssr`
4. `yarn start`
5. open http://localhost:4200